# Change tag Content of a WebBrowser from a Timer

Tags: c#, delegates, webbrowser-control

I am using a **webBrowser control** for displaying  a webpage. While creating webBrowser I can change the value of a predefined tag. My problem is that in a `timer_tick` I want to change the same tag value. Here is my code

```
if (currentlyRunningObject.Equals(webBrowser1))
{
     Application.DoEvents();
     HtmlElement test = webBrowser1.Document.All["test"];
     test.InnerHtml = "mmmmmmmm";
}
```

In the `timer_tick` I did the same thing but **VS stopped debugging** after it complete the last line execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the solution here is code in timer tick

```
webBrowser1.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        HtmlElement token2 = webBrowser1.Document.All["token2"];
                        //MessageBox.Show(token2.InnerHtml);
                        token2.InnerHtml = currentToken;
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer's tick fires in a thread pool thread. You must [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) any code using the webBrowser1  to marshall it to the UI thread or use the [SynchronizationClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do the same.

```
Action a = () => 
{
     HtmlElement test = webBrowser1.Document.All["test"];
     test.InnerHtml = "mmmmmmmm";
};
webBrowser1.Invoke(a);
```